# Correct Grand Total in Pivot Using Calculated Field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot table which looks like

```
Date        Sum of DURATION   Capped Daily Total
03-Jan                  9.5                  8.0
04-Jan                  6.0                  6.0
05-Jan                 10.5                  8.0
06-Jan                  4.5                  4.5
Grand Total            30.5                  8.0
```

As you can see, the Grand Total for Capped Daily Total is incorrect.
In this example:

1. `Date` column is added as a Row and comes from source data. It has been Grouped By: Days
2. `Sum of DURATION` is added in the Values section and comes from the source data.
3. `Capped Daily Total` is a *computed field*. The formula used is `= MIN('DURATION', 8)`

When calculating the grand total it appears that excel has computed the Grand Total and then used the formula `= MIN('DURATION (HOURS)', 8)` to cap it to 8 hours. I don't want the formula to apply to the Grand Total - only to the rows. The grand total should be a simple `SUM` formula.

How can I achieve this requirement in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a issue with pivot tables see [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211470). To get around this you can add the Daily Capped Total formula to you table itself instead of the pivot table and the field will calculate correctly.

[image: Table With Daily Capped Total]

Another solution to get the total would be to place a formula outside the pivottable and sum the column minus the grand total.

```
=SUM(G:G)-GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Daily Capped Total",$E$1)
```

Based off you description of the raw data you could use this formula. It looks for the first occurrence of the date in the range and if it matches the current row number it will sum and min to get your requirement.

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$15,0)=ROW()-1,MIN(SUMIF($A$2:$A$15,A2,$B$2:$B$15),8),0)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't add it to the table itself as the formula applies to the Day, not to the time entry in the source data. The source data has many time slots in a single day. I use the "Group By" feature on the pivot table to group this data into Days instead.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your raw data?

Comment: I just added another solution based off your description of the raw data. It should suit your needs but may require some changes to fit to your data source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there not some setting in a Pivot that says "don't use the function when calculating the grand total, just sum the numbers in the column"? Seems like this would be necessary for all kinds of calculations... If there is no other way then I will accept your answer as the right one.

Comment: You're welcome. In the link I included Microsoft's explains the issue. During my research I haven't found anything that fixes this in the pivot table itself.