# Pivot Table's Calculated Field doesn't display Grand Total Correctly

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following Excel file: https://ufile.io/n9ed0

Which looks like this:

[image]

I have the calculated field `Break Lateness` to determine how late an "agent" is from his Break 1 by using the following formula:

`IF( 'Break 1' > TIME(0,15,0) , 'Break 1' - TIME(0,15,0), TIME(0,0,0) )`

The formula seems to work fine on cell range: `C3:C12`. But the Grand total in `C2` and `C13` is not correct.

I tried changing the time format but I'm unable to determine the reason why the sum is not being computed and displayed in the format I'd like.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Excel since many years... See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211470/calculated-field-returns-incorrect-grand-total-in-excel). I don't know when it will be solved.

I have tried to trick it, e.g. by creating an intermediate field holding the complex calculation, but this is not sufficient... (if I find a valid workaround, I will post it here).

Comment: If found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436099/correct-grand-total-in-pivot-using-calculated-field]. However, it is not always feasible...